# How to auto-generate methods of the implemented interface

Tags: interface, phpstorm, interface-implementation

Is there a way in PhpStorm to automatically generate the empty methods that are required by the interface the given class is implementing?

Say we have an Interface with 3 methods - when defining the new class that implements this interface - some option to auto-generate containers for all required methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From my comment: You could try <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This normaly shows up a small "dialog" to autogenerate phpdoc, functions, etc.

Comment: Just to highlight - I'm on Mac and it's Ctrl + Enter - then select Implement Methods. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16):

Sure, you can.

There are 3 ways to do it :

1. Press

   ```
   Ctrl + I
   ```
2. On main menu, click

   ```
   Code --> Implement Methods
   ```
3. On the code editor, press right click on your mouse, then click

   ```
   Generate --> Implement Methods
   ```

After that, you can select one or some method(s), then click OK.

Comment: If you're implementing an interface, you're required to implement every method, so why would you only select some methods?

Comment: abstract classes