# PhpStorm: Implementing a new interface function in ALL classes

Tags: php, phpstorm

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052463/phpstorm-auto-generate-methods-of-the-implemented-interface/36152731?noredirect=1) there is a shortcut to implement interfaces in a class.

Thank you for @Adi Priyanto answer, it is perfect for a one time generation.
Is there a way to do this for multiple files at one time?

I have a Factory Interface and a LOT of files implementing it. Adding a method to the interface is PITA if I have to generate them one by one in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28273 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.