# Automatically update Interfaces in PhpStorm when you add new public methods

Tags: phpstorm

Quite like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052463/how-to-auto-generate-methods-of-the-implemented-interface), but the exact opposite.

I have many classes that are having only one Interface, or the main interface being the first one. I want PhpStorm to automatically create new Interface entries when I i.e. use "Create Getters and Setters" or anything else, like creating public methods on my own.

Is there any feature or module or setting that I can use to do that, maybe even only case by case?

I haven't found a module for it.

Comment: That would support an antipattern meaning you develop explicit implementation before interface implementation so I guess you wont find anything.
Why dont you just generate the getters on your interface and then use `Implement Methods` in your classes?

Comment: @CodeSpirit because the refactoring/generation tools do not work like this in the Interface, sadly. It would only be an antipattern if the process order of this is not going to be done anyway (i.e. declare first in interface, then implement in concrete class vs declare in concrete class, then copy it over to interface). The interface is after all only an API anyway and for example Symfony generates bulk methods on its own with the make bundle, as an real life example where this might be useful.